# Как выбрать элемент из IEnumerable?

Tags: c#, linq, ienumerable

```
IEnumerable<Book> books = db.Books// через Entity Framework из бд беру модель
```

В модели Book есть уникальный Id. Как выбрать элемент из IEnumerable по Id=1?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

О, есть варианты:

```
Book book = db.Books.First(x => x.Id == 1);
```

или:

```
Book book = db.Books.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Id == 1);
```

Разница в том, что первый бросит исключение, если нет книги с Id = 1, второй вернёт null.

Это самые базовые, есть ещё вариант с .Single и .SingleOrDefault

Разницы между .Single и .First для первичного ключа нет, но если бы вы выбирали по какому-нибудь ключу, где возможны дубликаты, то .First вернул бы первый, а и .Single и .SingleOrDefault - дополнительно проверяют, что элемент гарантированно один и падает, если это не так.

И ещё (только для случая, если поле - первичный ключ):

```
Book book = db.Books.Find(1);
```